# Turn on/off using switch

Tags: switches, logic-gates

Well I have an exercise, there is a room, which have two door, there is `lamp` and `switches`. I need circuit that can turn on/off from both doors, switches are `SPST`.

Comment: You need an SPDT switch. Or an XOR circuit with relays or logic IC.

Comment: so, what have you tried so far, what have you considered, where was a problem? Not a free "do my homework" site, you know, but a bunch of people very eager to help you understand something that you can't answer yourself.

Comment: How many SPST switches are you allowed?

Comment: That's a good question @JackCreasey ;)

Comment: There's always string... rustic family vacation cottage had a pull chain light in a hallway with a string extending the chain running through eye hooks on the wall.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework without an attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only two SPST switches that would not be possible without more components.

However, since you said circuit, and not just wiring, you could add a couple of SPDT relays as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGmGaU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**NOTE:** Since each switch works one relay, it basically turns the SPST switch into a SPDT switch. Ultimately, using the right switches would have been better, assuming the voltages and currents on the switches matches the load. However, if your control switches are say 12V and the lamp is mains voltage, a circuit like this would be prudent.

**NOTE2** Of course, as Jack Creasey eluded, you COULD "[MacGyver it](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/macgyver)" and use two SPST switches at each door, one up, one down and glue/screw a bar across the toggles so they act in tandem as one SPDT switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0QkUM.png)</sup>

[image]

Comment: It appears the op only has SPST switches ....why would relays be ok?

Comment: @JackCreasey it's not if you read the question as.. "use these only". Hence my sentence #2.

Comment: Hey @Trevor. I can see a third screw terminal in each of those switches. You've used the wrong ones. ;^)

Comment: @Transistor ya that's the ground lug.... I should hide it though.. you are right.

Comment: Ah. That explains it. I'm not familiar with that switch type. Don't bother fixing it. Oh! You've done it already!

Comment: @Transistor lol too late :)

Comment: Nicely done MacGyver answer @Trevor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a horrible solution but it satisfies the user requirement specifications:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6GRdi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. EXOR lamp function with SPST switches.*

This arrangement relies on dropping half the supply voltage across the lamp and the remainder through a series resistor. This wastes as much power as the lamp consumes.

The horribleness comes from the fact that if either switch is turned on four times as much power is dissipated in the resistor as in the lamp. If both switches are turned on we waste eight times the power with no light!

It could be a workable solution for a low current LED application but not for a mains lamp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE0KuX.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Same principle of operation for a bi-directional LED or a single LED.*